# How to use expressions by name to select multiple pods to apply labels or annotations?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to understand how the following commands works and what kind of expressions are supported:

```
kubectl label pod foo{1..3} fizz=buzz
```

The `foo{1..3}` selects:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
```

I couldn't have found any documentation so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is the GNU Bash [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) extension syntax.  Some other shells like zsh support it too, but it is not one of the [Word Expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) in the POSIX shell spec; it won't work with some minimalist shells like the default dash shell in Debian GNU/Linux or the Busybox shell in an Alpine Docker image.

That means this is expanded by your local shell, to construct the arguments to `kubectl`.  Most of the expansion possibilities focus on filenames or environment variables.  (`foo*` would match local files whose names begin with `foo`, not Kubernetes pods.)  Potentially you could find `$(command)` substitution or `$(( 1 + 2 ))` arithmetic substitution useful.  There's not any broader Kubernetes name-matching syntax that gets used here, this is exclusively local-shell processing.